# When to use past perfect continuous and simple past tense?

Tags: grammar, simple-past-vs-past-perfect

What's the difference between:
"I had been working for ABC for 5 years" and "I worked in ABC company for 5 years". I feel that both are correct but cannot figure out the differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sentence is complete in itself grammatically but needs a context of previous time or circumstance for completeness of meaning. For examples: “When I was promoted, I had been working ...”; “by the time war started, I had been working ...”.

The second statement is complete grammatically and in meaning. It states a fact that is true regardless of when it became true.